# Angular Testing - Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm fairly new to angular and I'm testing a component that is injected an array via `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` and prints some info from each element. I am however running into the following error

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
    at NgForOf.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js:3161:1)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:18540:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:19801:1)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:19763:1)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20397:1)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20357:1)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///DynamicTestModule/TechniqueDetailsComponent.ngfactory.js:246:5)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:20349:1)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:19745:1)
    at callViewAction (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js:19986:1)
```

The component works correctly, however the test is failing. Do I need to provide actual testing data for the test to pass in this case? If so how do I do that?

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TechniqueDetailsComponent } from './technique-details.component';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

describe('TechniqueDetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: TechniqueDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TechniqueDetailsComponent>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TechniqueDetailsComponent ],
      providers: [ { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} } ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TechniqueDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-technique-details',
  templateUrl: './technique-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./technique-details.component.scss']
})
export class TechniqueDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**EDIT:**

component.html

```html
<section class="mat-typography">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title class="mat-h1">Technique(s)</h1>
  <div mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-tab-group>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
        <mat-tab label="{{item.name}}">

          <mat-card class="example-card" >
            <mat-card-header>
              <mat-card-subtitle class="mat-body-2">{{item.description}}<br/></mat-card-subtitle>
            </mat-card-header>

            <mat-card-content>
              <mat-divider></mat-divider>

              <br/><mat-label><b>Structure:</b></mat-label><br/>
              <mat-tab-group>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let mod of item.structure.modules">
                <mat-tab label="{{mod.name}}">
                  <mat-tab-group>
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let pha of mod.phases">
                      <mat-tab label="{{pha.name}}">
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let tsk of pha.tasks">
                          <br/>{{tsk.type}}
                          <br/>{{tsk.description}}
                          <br/>{{tsk.role}}
                          <br/>{{tsk.resources}}
                        </ng-container>
                      </mat-tab>
                  </ng-container>
                </mat-tab-group>

                </mat-tab>
                </ng-container>
              </mat-tab-group>

              <br/><mat-label><b>Rules:</b></mat-label>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let i of item.rules">
                {{i}}<br/>
              </ng-container>

              <mat-label><b>Target Audience:</b></mat-label>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let i of item.target_audience">
                {{i}}<br/>
              </ng-container>

              <mat-label><b>Resolution Scope:</b></mat-label>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let i of item.resolution_scope">
                {{i}}<br/>
              </ng-container>

              <mat-label><b>Delivery Mode:</b></mat-label>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let i of item.delivery_mode">
                {{i}}<br/>
              </ng-container>

              <mat-label><b>Interaction:</b></mat-label>
              <ng-container *ngFor="let i of item.interaction">
                {{i}}<br/>
              </ng-container>



              <mat-list>
              <mat-label><b>Learning Objectives:</b></mat-label><br/>
              <mat-list-item *ngFor="let lo of item.learning_objectives">
                {{lo.knowledge_category}} =>  {{lo.behaviour}}
              </mat-list-item>
              </mat-list>

              <ng-container *ngIf="item.affective_objectives.length > 0">
                <mat-list>
                <mat-label><b>Affective Objectives:</b></mat-label><br/>
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let i of item.affective_objectives">
                  {{i}}
                </mat-list-item>
                </mat-list>
              </ng-container>

              <ng-container *ngIf="item.social_objectives.length > 0">
                <mat-list>
                <mat-label><b>Social Objectives:</b></mat-label><br/>
                <mat-list-item *ngFor="let i of item.social_objectives">
                  {{i}}
                </mat-list-item>
                </mat-list>
              </ng-container>

            </mat-card-content>

          </mat-card>

        </mat-tab>
      </ng-container>

    </mat-tab-group>



  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It's hard to be sure what's causing the error without seeing the code for `TechniqueDetailsComponent`, but it looks like the template for that component is trying to use `*ngFor` without an iterable (i.e. an array). Can you post the TS and HTML for the component?

Comment: I've edited my post with those two files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ngFor does not work with object literals**

The line

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
```

in component.html says "take collection called data, and for each member of that collection create an  element. However, the line in your test file

```javascript
providers: [ { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} } ],
```

you set data to be an object, {}. Change the line to use an empty array instead and your error should go away:

```
providers: [ { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: [] } ],
```